# Sponsored events

Tags: wordpress

I am just browsing CiviCRM as a possible tool to run an annual sponsored event. I'm a bit overwhelmed by the size of the tool and I wondered if someone could please point me in a good direction to get me started?

The event is an annual sponsored cycle ride. Each participant signs up with a range of options:

- Distance (100km or 30km)
- Transport to the event (chargeable) (Yes or No)

They have their own fundraising page with a link that they can promote by email or on Social Media and friends click on a "Give Now" button to sponsor them. The fundraising pages are customisable with a photo of the participant and the ability to write a few lines explaining why they are taking part. It would be good to be able to pre-populate the page with some default text.

Some participants take part over several years and it would be good to be able to track their previous participation and fund-raising over the years.

It would be good for each sponsor to be able to view all their donations. Some people sponsor several participants.

Answer (score 1):

PCP (or Personal Campaign Pages) is the tool you are looking for. You can investigate this a bit more by going to a demo site eg and looking at one of the Contribution Pages eg https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/contribute/pcp?reset=1&action=update&id=1 which is the tab where you set up the PCPs and then at

https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/contribute/campaign?action=add&reset=1&pageId=1&component=contribute where you can create your PCP eg https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/pcp/info?reset=1&id=2&ap=0 (which will disappear within 24 hours when the site gets reset)

it currently shows the widget for my $500 goal.

Donating for multiple folk in one go can't be done via this approach. Only way I could think would be using PriceSets on Events but that has no way of letting each fundraiser see how they are going.

HTH